# How to mount an unmounted USB device Ubuntu using command?

Tags: 14.04, mount, umount

I first eject device using sudo eject /dev/sr1. And then sudo umount /dev/sr1.
But now it's not showing me the device which i'm unmounted. I want to mount it using command.

Comment: This [question on U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7108/103151) describes that it is  **not possible** to re-mount _ejected_ devices! You can only re-mount _unmounted_ devices.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

to check which is the usb disk. In case, for example, of /dev/sdb1, then

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 path_to_mount_point
```

more reference [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB).